# How to convert a WORD file to .txt with different header?

Tags: vba, ms-word, type-conversion

I have got a lot of word file (~5000) with different header what i read with a macro and merge these multiple word document placed in a folder into one document.

Here the relevant code:

```
Sub MergeDocs() 
    Dim rng As Range 
    Dim MainDoc As Document 
    Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String 
    Dim Count As Long 
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 
        .Title = "Pick folder" 
        .AllowMultiSelect = False 
        If .Show Then 
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator 
        Else 
            Exit Sub 
        End If 
    End With 
    Set MainDoc = Documents.Add 
    strFile = Dir$(strFolder & "*.doc") ' can change to .docx
    Count = 0 
    Do Until strFile = "" 
        Count = Count + 1 
        Set rng = MainDoc.Range 
        With rng 
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd 
            If Count > 1 Then 
                .InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage 
                .End = MainDoc.Range.End 
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd 
            End If 
            .InsertFile strFolder & strFile 
        End With 
        strFile = Dir$() 
    Loop 
    MsgBox ("Files are merged") 
lbl_Exit: 
    Exit Sub 
End Sub
```

It is working, but when I am trying to save file as .txt, the header+footer lose..is it any way which one I can save this header part to a .txt file too? (as I wrote, in every document has got different header.)

EDIT:

```
Sub MergeDocs()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MainDoc As Document
    Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
    Dim Count As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Pick folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Set MainDoc = Documents.Add
    strFile = Dir$(strFolder & "*.doc") ' can change to .docx
    Count = 0
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim head As String, foot As String

    Do Until strFile = ""
        Set doc = Documents.Open(strFile)
        head = doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
        foot = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
        doc.Close False

        Count = Count + 1
        Set rng = MainDoc.Range
        With rng
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            If Count > 1 Then
                .InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage
                .End = MainDoc.Range.End
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .InsertAfter head
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .InsertFile strFolder & strFile
        .InsertAfter foot
    End With
    strFile = Dir$()
Loop
    MsgBox ("Files are merged")
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: So far you do not open the files before you append them to your main doc. YOu will have to do this. Then - presuming you only have one header/footer - you can read header and footer into variables like this: `head = doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.text` and `foot = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.text` and insert these texts before respectively after you `.InsertFile`.  Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, i need this logic! Because in the header part i have got for example the date part what i need and of course it is different in all word documents.
How is it looking in the code? Can you write an answer? And I can try it and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This is not fully tested but should get you going.

I have only altered your Do loop. Replace, try out and have fun:

```
Dim doc As Document
Dim head As String, foot As String

Do Until strFile = ""
    Set doc = Documents.Open(strFolder & strFile)
    head = doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.text
    foot = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.text
    doc.Close False

    Count = Count + 1
    Set rng = MainDoc.Range
    With rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If Count > 1 Then
            .InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage
            .End = MainDoc.Range.End
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .InsertAfter head
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .InsertFile strFolder & strFile
        .InsertAfter foot
    End With
    strFile = Dir$()
Loop
```

Comment: There is an error in this code, it is not running :S

Comment: On line `Set doc = Documents.Open(strFile)`, right? Yeah, I forgot to add the path before the file name. Try again, see edited code line above.